# Zapier Webhooks GETing nested JSON

Tags: zapier

I am trying to submit invoices to Quickbooks Online with line items.

Zapier does have line item support but only a handful of apps support it.  The webhooks by Zapier is promising but so far I have tried a variety of tricks to enable line items without success.

If I send the invoice object as an array, it posts one invoice per line item.

If I send it as a nested JSON, ie this data:

```
{"billid":"MN001233","orgname":"My Org","generated_date":"10/01/2019","result_array":["Eligibility Details ,3244,0.1500,486.6000","Eligibility Pass through fee,11,0.0300,0.3300","Eligibility Pass through fee,36,0.0500,1.8000"]}
```

It treats the whole result_array as basically a string.

How can I send it so that multiple line items are supported in the same call?

Comment: What information are you trying to isolate? Is it the 'result_array' data?

Comment: What is your current flow? `Trigger = Webhook by Zapier` + `Event= Create Invoice by QuickBooks`?